# Possible to use "Blackberry Protect" in conjunction with a BES IT Policy?

Tags: mobile, blackberry

Is it possible to use [Blackberry Protect](http://us.blackberry.com/apps-software/protect/) in conjunction with a BES IT policy?  If so, what settings are incompatible?

So far I discovered that Memory encryption appears to be incompatible, but I'd like to see if anyone has more complete information than my trial by error approach.

[More info](http://www.blackberry.com/btsc/dynamickc.do?externalId=KB25061&sliceID=2&command=show&forward=nonthreadedKC&kcId=KB25061)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it creates a partition on the device for the end user that doesn't allow you to mix the personal data with business data. A lot of 3rd party companies are doing this.